# How to prove that a Banach space of analytic functions containing $H^\infty$ except the origin is simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analyticity

If $X$ is a Banach space of analytic functions on the unit disk $D$ which contains the space of analytic bounded functions on $D$, how can I prove that $X\setminus\{0\}$ is simply connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any Banach space of dimension $>2$, $X \backslash \{0\}$ is simply connected.

EDIT: Hint: given a closed curve $\gamma: {\mathbb S^1} \to X \backslash \{0\}$, first deform to a polygonal curve.  That polygonal curve is in a finite-dimensional subspace...

Comment: Could you please give me a hint of the proof for the infinite dimensional case? I guess it is different from the finite dimensional case...